# Bootsrap modals are not appearing in the rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am implementing jquery on devise views on a sample rails application. Before I implement it on a production code I wanted to first try it on a sample app.

I have a **welcome** controller and view

**routes.rb** is as follows

```
get 'welcome/index'
devise_for :users
root 'welcome#index'
```

And the partial templates for both `register` and `login` lies in the following files as follows:

**app/views/welcome/_login_modal.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="login">

<div class="modal-header">

<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>

<h2>Sign in</h2>

</div>

<div class="modal-body">

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br />

<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />

<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>

<div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>

<% end -%>

<%= f.submit "Sign in", :class => 'btn btn-small btn-success' %>
<% end %>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</div>

</div>
```

I have added my javascript code in the **application.html.erb** file 
itself

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PopupDevise</title>
<%= link_to "Login", "#login", "data-toggle" => "modal", :class => 'btn btn-small' %>

<%= link_to "Sign up", "#sign_up", "data-toggle" => "modal", :class => 'btn btn-small btn-success' %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $(function ()

    { $("#myModal").modal({show:false }); </script>
</head>
<body>
<%= render "welcome/login_modal" %>

<%= render "welcome/sign_up_modal" %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when I run `rails s` everything is visible. And when I click on either `Login` or `Sign Up` button the screen goes transparent grey but I don't see any popups modals. I am not that good in js or jquery part still learning. Could somebody please tell me how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with this.

Remove
`hide` and `in`
from line

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="login">
```

You should be able to see modal when you click "Login" button.

Also remove bellow script tag inside `<head> </head>` as you are not using a modal with id `myModal`.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function ()

{ $("#myModal").modal({show:false }); </script>
```